# Managing SSH keys for Heroku from mac and windows

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

At home I have a `Mac book pro`, at work I use a `Windows 7` machine. I've created an `Heroku` account and added SSH keys from both machines. If I run `heroku keys` I see the 2 keys listed.

I initially created a small app and deployed to heroku from my `Mac book pro`.

Whilst working on my `Windows 7` machine I'm trying to `clone` the app source code from Heroku.

`heroku git:clone -a the_name_of_my_app`

But I'm getting a `permission denied (publickey)`, `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Can anyone explain how I work with `heroku` from both `Mac book pro` and `Windows 7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working on two different machines, and that implies different SSH identities. You have to let heroku know about the other set of keys. Run the following query:

```
mac/win$ heroku keys
```

in the windows box prompt, and you should see the keys that heroku knows about, and they would either be none or your Mac keys only.

Next, if you know the location of your SSH keys on the windows box, run

```
win$ heroku keys:add path\to\id_rsa.pub
```

otherwise if you have no SSH identity (keys) yet generated for the Windows box, simply run `heroku keys:add` and follow the prompts.